# Do Apache config files support block commenting?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

You can use `#` to comment out individual lines.
Is there a syntax for commenting out entire blocks?

I've tired surrounding the block (specifically a `<Directory>` block) with `<IfModule asdfasdf>...</IfModule>`, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I came across this post from a Google search for "Apache block comment".  Later, I discovered a non-perl, non-import solution from Apache's core documentation (although I'm sure this is very non-intended practice).  From the core documentation for Apache 2.0 http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html, you can see that the tag `<IfDefine>` will handily ignore statements when the parameter you specify does not exist:

```
<IfDefine IgnoreBlockComment>
...
</IfDefine>
```

So that'll successfully "comment" out the statements in between.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure if apache has such type of comments.

As a workaround, you can use include statement in the following way:

yourfile.conf:

```
<Directory>
  ....
</Directory>
```

When you want to comment this block, you just need to comment out the include line:

```
#include yourfile.conf
```

Comment: Sad :( I've heard NGinx has better easier configuration.

Comment: Comments aren't configuration. A good text editor will allow you to quickly add stuff to multiple lines, too. In Textmate, it's Option+Drag.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Apache doesn't support this.

But, if you're using `vim`, here's a tip (from my co-worker) to comment out a Apache config block.

For instance, given this snippet:

```
<Directory "a/b/c">
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For ^x\.y\.z\.t let_me_in
    Order allow,deny
    allow from env=let_me_in
    ErrorDocument 403 http://google.com
</Directory>
```

Put the cursor under the `D` character at the opening `<Directory ...>` line and type the following:

`V/Dir` -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

followed by:

`:s/^/#/` -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

- `V` - to highlight the current line
- `/Dir` - selects the whole block
- `:s/^/#/` - puts a `#` at the begin of each line

Comment: I think it's easier to just go in Visual Block mode on the opening tag, scroll down to the closing tag, and then do shift-I (big i) # Esc.